# How to set the <Col> size for every screen size in React?

Tags: reactjs, row, react-bootstrap, col

This is my code:

```
 <Row>
    <Col xs="11"> 
       Title
    </Col>
    <Col xs="1">
      <Button/ >
    </Col>
 </Row>
```

I wanna display the `title` and the `button` in on `Row` and the container for the title should almost be the entire screen (`11/12`). The container size of the button should be `1/12` of the screen. Is there a way so set this for every screen size? In my code it works if the screen is larger than `xs`. I dont know how to set the `Col size =11` for every screen size.

Thanks :-)

Comment: What is the framework do you  use to get <Row> and <Col>?

Comment: I use reactstrap